# Print dynamic code with javascript which is added a method depending on an argument

Tags: javascript

I need to print dynamic code. My idea is to print what is in the variable str but with X number of ".parentElement".

I don't know if using eval is the best, but I didn't find another way. It wouldn't be working for me anyway.

```
function getElementByClasses(elementLength, className, e) {

  for (let i = 0; i <= elementLength; i++) {
    
    const x = '.parentElement';
    const y = x.repeat(i);
    
    const str = `
        if (e.target${y}.classList.contains(className)) {
            const elementWithClass = e.target${y};
       
            return elementWithClass;
        }
    `;
    eval(str);
  }
})
```

Comment: First, `eval()` is evil and should really never be used in 99.99999% of use cases as it opens up security holes in your code and introduces performance issues. Second, please clarify what it is you are trying to do *I need to print dynamic code* doesn't really mean much to us. If you could edit your question and include the relevant HTML and CSS so that we could attempt to run your code and see what it does, that is always helpful.

Comment: No need for `eval`. You can simply access the nested property in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're doing, I think using `.closest` alone would be better:

```
function getElementByClasses(elementLength, className, e) {
  const found = e.target.closest('.' + className)
  if (found) return found;
}
```

If you need to manually iterate over the parents for some reason, and you need to limit the number of parents iterated over to `elementLength`, then reassign an element while navigating to its parent inside the loop:

```
function getElementByClasses(elementLength, className, e) {
  let elm = e.target;
  for (let i = 0; i <= elementLength; i++) { // should this be <, not <= ?
    if (elm?.classList.contains(className)) {
      return elm;
    }
    elm = elm?.parentElement;
  }
}
```

(but `.closest` would really make more sense, if at all possible)

Comment: I think you only need one loop. Just assign `let elm = e.target` outside the loop and do `elm = elm.parentElement` if `elm` doesn't contain the class. I could imagine `elementLength` is just used because they didn't know better but who knows...